# 1D convolution sequence in keras

Tags: functional-programming, keras, convolution

I am a noob trying to build a network to classify 2 sequences of floats to  one of 16450 different integers. I have 70408 samples and I have padded each sample to have 1400 values. So 1 sample has 2 column vectors eg. [104.243,120.12...], [125.25,14.556...]. Both my x_train is size (70408,1400). I am trying to use keras' functional API but can't seem to figure out the right input shape. Any help would be appreciated.

```python
samples = 70408
mass_size = 1400
intensity_size = 1400
output_size = 16450

mass_input = Input(shape=(samples,mass_size), dtype='float32')
mass_net = layers.Conv1D(32,5,activation='relu')(mass_input)
mass_net = layers.AveragePooling1D(3)(mass_net)
mass_net = layers.Conv1D(16,5,activation='relu')(mass_net)
mass_net = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(mass_net)

intensity_input = Input(shape=(samples,intensity_size), dtype='float32')
intensity_net = layers.Conv1D(32,5,activation='relu')(intensity_input)
intensity_net = layers.AveragePooling1D(3)(intensity_net)
intensity_net = layers.Conv1D(16,5,activation='relu')(intensity_net)
intensity_net = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(intensity_net)

concatenated = layers.concatenate([mass_net,intensity_net],axis=-1)

output = layers.Dense(output_size,activation='softmax')(concatenated)


print(mass_data.shape, intensity_data.shape)
model = Model([mass_data,intensity_data],output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

model.fit([mass_data,intensity_data],y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=128)
```

The error I keep getting is:

```python
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-aab93c439dd0> in <module>()
     28 
     29 print(mass_data.shape, intensity_data.shape)
---> 30 model = Model([mass_data,intensity_data],output)
     31 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
     32 

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name)
   1528 
   1529         # Check for redundancy in inputs.
-> 1530         if len(set(self.inputs)) != len(self.inputs):
   1531             raise ValueError('The list of inputs passed to the model '
   1532                              'is redundant. '

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: you need 3D data for convolutions 1D. `(samples, length, channelsOrFeatures)`.

Comment: I have successfully reshaped my input to (samples,length,features) but I am still getting the exact same error. Does it matter if my sequences are row vectors or column vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
model = Model([mass_data,intensity_data],output)
```

You should use the input tensors you created, not numpy data:

```
model = Model([mass_input, intensity_input],output)
```

---

Another problem, related to my old comment is the `input_shape`.

Since you now have your data as (samples, length, features), you need `input_shape=(length,features)`

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! <3

Comment: :D -- If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Is it wasteful if I use a functional model instead of sequential. I figured I could probably use 1 Conv1D by merging my data together of size (70408,1400,2)

Comment: No problem.... but it may depend on the expected results. But it's an open question. You can also use only one input by concatenating the input data too.